# Acer Aspire V3-772G with WIN10 default boot device missing

Tags: boot, bios, data-recovery, acer-aspire, file-recovery

my 2 years old, out of warranty, **Acer Aspire V3-772G with WIN10** is giving me a message ‘default boot device missing’.
I tried to take out the battery for a few seconds, take out the HDD and gently clean the inside of the laptop as well as the HDD from dust. I have also followed up on a thread where somebody with the same error but on WIN8 and a different Acer laptop was told to download the BIOS install file (**isST2212.exe**), Create a recovery drive and run it on a USB drive, change the Bios to Legacy Boot, move the USB HDD as the first boot device and end up in a WIN8 recovery console. I then went into the advanced options and into the command prompt where I went to D:/isST2212.exe … A new window titled **InsydeFlash V5.37** pops up saying that my current BIOS ID is: Aspire V3-772 version: V1.15
And the New BIOS ID is: Storm2 version V2.12

Here I get an error that says the following: This BIOS is not for your Notebook PC. The version of ROM file is not newer than that of BIOS.

I Went on **www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers** where I looked onto Acer Aspire V3-772G BIOS drivers and the newest one is V1.15 which is the one I already have.

A LOT depends on me getting back into the desktop and backing up files that are in the laptop. I only need an hour more with it, PLEASE HELP, its serious.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a BIOS, motherboard or HDD fault. 
If you can access the BIOS, check whether the HDD is still recognized and set as primary / default boot device.
If it's 'only' about the data on the disk: 
Have the disk placed in / connected to a working PC and access it from there.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Im in the BIOS information and I can see the HDD model name and serial number so I think, that the HDD is recognised and should be therefore working. The HDD is set as the first one on the list, but I still get the same error saying: 

PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting Broadcom PXE ROM
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Please stay with me, I need your help badly... :D